# Select statement that combines similar rows with certain ids?

Tags: mysql, select, merge, field

I have a warehouse_products table which defines how many products in the warehouses

so lets say I have 20 records/rows in the table, some rows may contain the same product id but in a different warehouse

I need to create select statement that give every product one row, and in this row I must have the quantity in warehouse A and warehouse B ..

so in the end I will get for example 10 rows that contain all the data

[alt text http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/1948/stackoverflow.jpg](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/1948/stackoverflow.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p1.wh_id as whA_id, p2.wh_id as whB_id, 
    coalesce(p1.p_id, p2.p_id) as p_id, p1.qty as qty_A, 
    p2.qty as qty_B, coalesce(p1.enabled, p2.enabled) as enabled
from warehouse_products p1
full outer join warehouse_products p2 on p1.p_id = p2.p_id
    and p1.wh_id = 'A' and p2.wh_id = 'B'
```

**Update:**

I forgot that MySql does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`. I don't have time to update the query right now, but there are examples of how to get the same results [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/).

Comment: perhaps I did't make my self clear,, I don't want to take the sum of the quantity
I want to have 
warehouseA_id -- warehouseA_quantity -- warehouseB_id -- warehouseB_quantity -- Product_id

so I want to take two rows and merge them into 1, and changing the names

Comment: thanks
I tried it, it didn't work at first
but when I removed "FULL OUTER" it worked, but it only showed me the records where (wh_id = A AND wh_id = B)
and if the products that are in warehouse A only (or B only) arent shown

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT id, domain_id, wh_product_id, SUM(item_bom.qty_bom) qty_total
FROM warehouse_products GROUP BY id, domain_id, wh_product_id
```

You won't be able to show **warehouse_id**.  Nor **wh_product_id**, I would guess -- I included it here, but if have 20 rows instead of 10, remove it.